# libgdx android studio - cannot resolve method drawMultiLine and symbol HAlignment

Tags: android-studio, compiler-errors, libgdx

I'm facing this error in android studio and libgdx, when trying to build/run:

> Error:(118, 79) Gradle: error: cannot find symbol variable HAlignment

And android studio also marks "drawMultiLine" and "HAlignment" as red saying in the source code java class:

> "Cannot resolve method
>   'drawMultiLine(com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch,
>   java.lang.String, float, float, int, ?)'" "Cannot resolve symbol
>   HAlignment"

Code block:

```
private void renderGuiGameOverMessage (SpriteBatch batch)
{
    float x = cameraGUI.viewportWidth / 2;
    float y = cameraGUI.viewportHeight / 2;
    if (worldController.isGameOver())
    {
        BitmapFont fontGameOver = Assets.instance.fonts.defaultBig;
        fontGameOver.setColor(1, 0.75f, 0.25f, 1);
        fontGameOver.drawMultiLine(batch, "GAME OVER", x, y, 0, BitmapFont.HAlignment.CENTER);
        fontGameOver.setColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
    }
}
```

Why it don't find the method?
How can i resolve this?

Thank's a lot!

Comment: which libgdx version do you use?

Comment: I fear you are using an deprecated api. (Did you update libgdx version in an old project or copy code from an old libgdx project?) There have been many changes with BitmapFont since libgdx version 1.5.6 see http://www.badlogicgames.com/wordpress/?p=3658  `BitmapFont.HAlignment` doesn't exist in newest libgdx anymore

Comment: the libgdx version is 1.6.0, the guide says the libgdx version used in the book is 0.1.2 (Learning LibGDX Game
Development
Second Edition).  
Align.CENTER also show the error "cannot resolve the symbol 'CENTER'" (imported import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Align;)

Comment: Actually it should be `Align.center` (in lowercase). Will update answer... Anyhow the best way to figure out what members a class has is to just type the classname + dot (Align.) and then see the suggestions that your IDE will show. Or just rightclick it and select "go to Declaration" from the menu. LibGDX is open-source so you can always see and review the code!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
fontGameOver.drawMultiLine(batch, "GAME OVER", x, y, 0, Align.center);
```

instead of:

```
fontGameOver.drawMultiLine(batch, "GAME OVER", x, y, 0, BitmapFont.HAlignment.CENTER);
```

Note that you need to import `com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Align` now.

Judging by the [bitmapfont refactoring post from the badlogicgames blog](http://www.badlogicgames.com/wordpress/?p=3658) this should work for you. See especially this points:

> BitmapFont.HAlignment is gone. Align is used instead. Align has been
>   moved to the utils package.

Comment: Thank's a lot!
The link you provided to me has the answer!
Simply replace this: fontGameOver.drawMultiLine(batch, "GAME OVER", x, y, 0, BitmapFont.HAlignment.CENTER); whit this:  fontGameOver.draw(batch, "GAME OVER", x, y);